# Meaning of integral in equation

Tags: calculus, integration

I was wondering that if $\int_0^xv(t)dt+C=\int v(x)dx$ where v is the velocity function and x is time, what is the meaning of $\int_0^xv(t)dt$ in the context of velocity or position or change in position? Does it even have any meaning because since $\int_0^xv(t)dt=\int v(x)dx-C$ and since C is unknown and $\int v(x)dx$ is an indefinite integral, I don't think $\int_0^xv(t)dt$ has meaning.

Comment: Physically in the expression $\int_0^x v(t) dt$, the upper limit of integration has the wrong units, so the expression is incorrectly labeled (i.e. really you are integrating against position and you just deceptively called the position along the integration $t$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Newton's law of motion, one has
\begin{align*}
\textbf{R} = \frac{\mathrm{d}\textbf{p}}{\mathrm{d}t} = m\frac{\mathrm{d}\textbf{v}}{\mathrm{d}t} = m\textbf{a}
\end{align*}

where $\textbf{R}$ represents the resultant force acting on the body, $t$ is the time variable, $\textbf{p} = m(t)\textbf{v}(t)$ is the linear momentum ($m$ stands for the mass, $\textbf{v}$ stands for the velocity and $\textbf{a}$ stands for the acceleration). If we consider that the mass is constant, we can factor out it from the derivative of $\textbf{p}$, as previously shown. Based on such equation, we can now answer your question. By definition, the acceleration $\textbf{a}(t)$ is the derivative of the velocity. The velocity $\textbf{v}(t)$, by its turn, is the derivative of the position $\textbf{s}(t)$. Therefore we can interpret the given integral as
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{T}\textbf{v}(t)\mathrm{d}t = \int_{0}^{T}\frac{\mathrm{d}\textbf{s}}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathrm{d}t = \int_{0}^{T}\mathrm{d}\textbf{s} = \textbf{s}(T) - \textbf{s}(0)
\end{align*}

Thus, if you know the velocity, you know the position and the acceleration as well. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The (definite) integral of the velocity between two times (in your case $0$ and $x$) is the (net) distance traversed in that time interval.

If you measure the position as the net distance from some fixed position you have a function whose derivative is the velocity. In that sense the position is an indefinite integral of the velocity. The "arbitrary constant" is there because the fixed starting position is arbitrary.